# How to add UIPickerView sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a requirement to make a UIPickerView look like the one in the image below.

It has 5 different sections with 2 rows each.

Section header titles should be a different color and non-selectable. Selectable items should be indented under each section and selectable.

[image: UIPickerView]

Answer (score -1):

```
 func configureDatePicker(){
        let datePicker = UIPickerView.init()
//        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
        txtDOB.inputView = datePicker

        noteToolbar =  UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
        let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(AboutYouViewController.datePicked))
        let btnCancel = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Cancel", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(AboutYouViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        let flexibleButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

        noteToolbar.items = [btnDone, flexibleButton, btnCancel]
        txtDOB.inputAccessoryView = noteToolbar
    }

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView( pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int

    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
                      numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }
    func pickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView,
                      titleForRow row: Int,
                                  forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return "Test"
    }
```

You can modify according to your requirements and can use the dalagate and datasource mehtods of pickerview. It is as easy to use as UITableView delegate and data source